# Web Push Same Subscriber Different Endpoint Issue

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push

I am trying to implement the **web-push** service in one of my projects. So, I actually need to know the actual subscriber numbers in my app. So what problem I am facing is, the service worker generates new endpoints for the same user and I didn't find any unique thing by which I can figure out if the subscriber exists or not.

All my users are also guest users so I don't have any unique thing. There is also an event called **onPushSubscriptionChange** which doesn't also work in other browsers except for Mozilla.

**So is there any way to uniquely identify a user?** Like if multiple endpoints are created for the same user then I want to replace the old endpoint with the new one in my database. I am not willing to use cookies also.

**Another thing is does firebase cloud messaging solves this issue?**

Thank you